# double.TryParse() ignores dots in my string

Tags: c#, string, parsing, double, c#-5.0

So I'm currently using the following code to parse a **string** into a **double**:

```
double.TryParse(resultLabel.Content.ToString(), out newNumber);
```

The parsing is executed but it ignores the . in the code. For Example:

- 3.3 gets parsed to 33
- 6.7 gets parsed to 67
- 9.5 gets parsed to 95

Does anyone know why is that and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

I tried to track it down with break points where it it parses falsely and it was immediately after this line.

Comment: What locale are you in?  What happens if you try to parse `3,3`, `6,7` or `9,5`?  Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-6.0

Comment: In you current culture `.` (dot) is a hroup separator which is ignored, while `,` (comma) is decimal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass culture that use "." as decimal separator (e.g. InvariantCulture)

```
var resultLabel = "3.3";
var success = double.TryParse(resultLabel, out var newNumber); //success is false
success = double.TryParse(resultLabel, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out newNumber); //success is true
```